# Configuring Java 8 systemd service to behave correctly with halts and restarts

Tags: systemd, java, services, shutdown

I am trying to get a Java 8 daemon/service to run on my Raspbian Pi (using [Raspbian Stretch Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/), which is based on Debian under the hood) at startup via `systemd`. Not only do I want it to run at startup, but if it crashes for some reason, I want `systemd` to restart it.

The executable JAR will be deployed to `/home/myuser/`, and because of a library ([pi4j](http://pi4j.com/)) that its using to communicate with the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins, the `java` command *must* be ran with `sudo`. Hence I can get the JAR to run manually by issuing:

```
sudo java -jar /home/myuser/myapp.jar
```

And it runs beautifully without any issues. Here's my best attempt at the `/lib/systemd/system/myapp.service` service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyApp Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=sudo java -jar /home/myuser/myapp.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I will make sure that `myapp.jar` uses something like the [Apache Commons Daemon lib](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/) to respond intelligently to the various linux SIG commands. But:

- It would be great if I could add `systemd` configurations above that would allow me to start the service manually with something like `systemctl start myapp`, shut it down with `systemctl stop myapp` and restart it with `systemctl restart myapp`
- I need `myapp.jar` to run (with `sudo`) at startup as well as to be restarted if it crashes (not sure how to accomplish the latter, and I'm not entirely positive I've configured the former above correctly or not...); and I'm hoping that this configuration would have the same effect as if I manually issued `systemctl start myapp`
- I plan on shutting down the Raspberry Pi with a manual `sudo halt -p` command, and I need that to have the same effect as if I manually ran `systemctl stop myapp`

**Any ideas as to what I can add to my `myapp.service` file to accomplish this?**

Comment: If your app is real daemon then you only need to make sure ``Type`` is correct (see ``man systemd.service``). To start it, use ``systemctl start myapp``. ``man systemctl`` for more info.

Comment: Thanks @user996142 (+1) - I just looked at the `man` for `systemctl` and it looks like I can start/stop/restart just like you say (`systemctl stop`, `systemctl restart`, etc.). However that doesn't help me: (1) configure `systemd` to automatically restart the service if it crashes/stop, and (b) assure that when `sudo halt -p` is issued manually, that the same SIG command is sent to my app as if I had issued a `systemctl stop` command. Any ideas?

Comment: about restart: https://jonarcher.info/2015/08/ensure-systemd-services-restart-on-failure/ . check ``man systemd.service``. ``halt`` sends ``SIGKILL`` probably, and if you use ``shutdown`` it shoud send ``SIGTERM`` which is the same as ``systemctl stop``. But you can configure any systemd service to use any signal. See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html (``man systemd.kill``)

Comment: @smeeb To automatically restart a service, see `Restart=` in `man systemd.service`. The default is `no`, i.e. the service is not restarted.

Comment: Thanks @JohanMyréen (+1) - I looked up `Restart=` and made some changes, can you please confirm that my service file looks right now and will accomplish the three bullet points I listed above? Thanks again!

Comment: It looks good to me, but the only way to know for sure is to test it.

Comment: Last question @JohanMyréen -- where in my example file am I specifying that `systemd` should start my service at startup? Just curious!

Comment: @smeeb Enabled (`systemctl enable exampleservice`) services are started automatically at boot.

Comment: Thanks @JohanMyréen -- but is there any way to "enable" a service via configuration, so I don't have to SSH into a machine and manually enable that service in the first place? That **has** to be possible!

Comment: You would have to SSH into the machine to edit the configuration anyway. I don't see the difference.

Comment: Hmmmm you're telling me that there's no way to automate the enabling of a service? Sorry, I'd have to disagree as I know config management solutions like Chef or Ansible can do this no sweat. It has to be possible!

Comment: If your goal is to create an image for provisioning your system, you will have to recreate what `systemctl enable` does: it creates the following symlink `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/myapp.service -> /lib/systemd/myapp.service`.